# How to add controls dynamically in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to add controls dynamically

Code:

.aspx

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text="Personal Information" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White"   runat="server" Width="854px" BackColor="SteelBlue" style="margin-top: 0px" Height="60px"> </asp:Label>
<div id="div1" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="panelPersonal" runat="server">
<div id="divreg" runat="server">
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
<tr>
<td class="style8">&nbsp; Visa Number:</td>
<td class="style20">&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
<td class="style22">&nbsp; Country Name:</td>
<td class="style23">&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style22">&nbsp; Type of Visa:</td>
<td class="style23">&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server">  </asp:DropDownList></td>
<td class="style22">&nbsp; Type of Entry:</td>
<td class="style23">&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style8">&nbsp; Expiry Date</td>
<td class="style20">
&nbsp;<%--<BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="BasicDatePicker4" runat="server" onselectionchanged="BasicDatePicker2_SelectionChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />--%>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="addnewtext" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="addnewtext_Click" width="76px" />

</div>
</form>
```

Here I am using User control

.ascx

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddVisaControl.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="Pyramid.AddVisaControl" %>
<div id="divreg" runat="server">
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
<tr>
<td> Visa Number:</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
<td> Country Name:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Type of Visa:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
<td> Type of Entry:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Expiry Date</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

.aspx.cs

Here is the problem If I click add button one row is added successfully but when I close and open again previously added rows also coming.

I think the problem is static int i = 0;

Any other way is there?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }

    static int i = 0;
    protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            AddVisaControl ac = (AddVisaControl)Page.LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ac);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
        }
    }
```

This is what I am getting

[image]

This is what I want, Like below image I want to do

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are right. This is because of static declaration of variable i. Any Specific reason to make it static.

Comment: Number of rows will be incremented if we use static

Answer (score 0):

can you use a repeater /gridview control in the place of place holder control  ,i think that is the best method for your situvation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this solution. It is different from the code you are using but still very easy.
You can use a Repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 user control code goes here but first put it in a div(example id - div1) with `style="display:none"`
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

on the server side you do this

```
rpt1.DataSource = Utils.GetRptTable(4); // will add the code 4 times but it will not be   visible
rpt1.DataBind();
```

Later in javascript on the page you can find the first div with id div1 that has style - display:none and show it. That way you will show the next "row" with fields.

**Edit 1**

If you can add all your fields in the user control in a single `<tr>` you don't need a div with style= display:none. You will just have to add this class="GridBody" to your `<tbody>` - like: `<tbody class="GridBody">`

Then you do this to the row:

```
<tr class="GridRow" id="row1" style="display: none">
...
</tr>
```

and the javascript to show the row is:

```
 function addRow() {
        var body = $(".GridBody");
        var indexOfNextRow = $('tr[class="GridRow"][hidden="false"]').length;
        var tr = $(".GridBody tr")[indexOfNextRow];
        tr.style.display = 'table-row';
        tr.setAttribute('hidden', 'false');
    }
```